# Decoding "unknown" strings to UTF-8 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, utf-8, decode

I have a text source that sends me encoded Strings, for the most part, the JavaScript function `decodeURIComponent(escape(str))` works, But I've logged some weird "unknown" characters that broke the decodeURIComponent function, for now I have a workaround with replaceAll:

```
function fixWeirdCharacters(str){
  return str.replaceAll('Ã&nbsp;', "a").replaceAll('Ã“','O').replaceAll('ÃƒÂ‡ÃƒÂƒO','CAO').replaceAll('Ãš','U').replaceAll('ÃƒÂ','A').replaceAll('ÃƒÂ³','o').replaceAll('Ã‡Ã•','CO').replaceAll('Ã‰','E');
}
```

the following characters gave me error so far (encoded character = expected string):

```
Ã&nbsp = à
Ã“ = Ó
ÃƒÂ‡ÃƒÂƒO = ÇÂO
Ãš = Ú
ÃƒÂ = À
ÃƒÂ³ = ó
Ã‡Ã• = ÇÕ
Ã‰ = É
```

the assumption of the correct character was made by looking at the entire word, the main purpose is to decode it to UTF-8 and use it on regular HTML 5 page

Any idea of what might be creating those characters or how to decode them properly using JavaScript only?

Obs: I tried to decode them on PHP using urldecode(), and the result is an "?" box character..

Comment: "decode it to UTF-8" - What encoding are you getting the text in? In order to decode something, you have to know its encoding.

Comment: A **double** [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python): `'ÃƒÂ‡ÃƒÂƒO' .encode('cp1252') .decode('utf8') .encode('latin1') .decode('utf8')` returns `'ÇÃO'`. Or a _simple mojibake_ `'Ã“' .encode('cp1252') .decode('utf8')` returns `'Ó'`

Comment: @HereticMonkey Its an api that gives me the text like this, I just receive the string, so I have to "figure" the encoding.